# regex: If string contains specific word within bracket, then remove bracket and its content

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Using regex, I want to detect if a specific word exists within brackets in a string, if it does, remove the bracket and it's content.

The words I want to target are:

```
picture
see
lorem
```

So, here are 3 string examples:

```
$text1 = 'Hello world (see below).';
$text2 = 'Lorem ipsum (there is a picture here) world!';
$text3 = 'Attack on titan (is lorem) great but (should not be removed).';
```

What regex can I use with `preg_replace()`:

```
$text = preg_replace($regex, '' , $text);
```

To remove these brackets and their content if they contain those words?

Result should be:

```
$text1 = 'Hello world.';
$text2 = 'Lorem ipsum world!';
$text3 = 'Attack on titan great but (should not be removed).';
```

Here's an [ideone](http://ideone.com/ga4I0y) for testing.

Comment: And where exactly are you stuck? Have you tried anything to get to your goal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the following approach (thanks to @Casimir for pointing out an error before!):

```
<?php
$regex = '~
            (\h*\(                             # capture groups, open brackets
                [^)]*?                         # match everything BUT a closing bracket lazily
                (?i:picture|see|lorem)         # up to one of the words, case insensitive
                [^)]*?                         # same construct as above
            \))                                # up to a closing bracket
            ~x';                               # verbose modifier

$text = array();
$text[] = 'Hello world (see below).';
$text[] = 'Lorem ipsum (there is a picture here) world!';
$text[] = 'Attack on titan (is lorem) great but (should not be removed).';

for ($i=0;$i<count($text);$i++)
    $text[$i] = preg_replace($regex, '', $text[$i]);

print_r($text);
?>
```

See <kbd>[a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/dUetlR)</kbd> and [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nT0wI5/6).

Comment: Thank you for the code Jan. I have 2 issues left though with your regex. **If** the opening bracket has an empty space before it, then remove that empty space when removing the bracket: https://regex101.com/r/nT0wI5/2 It should still detect brackets that doesn't have space before them. Hope I am making sense.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson: Updated, see https://regex101.com/r/nT0wI5/3 I update the answer as well.

Comment: YES! This is exactly what I am looking for. One final request. Is there any way to make it case insensitive? So it should match with 'See' and 'SeE' too.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson: Yes, see updated answer: `(?i)` and `(?i-)` are inline modifiers, which turn on/off case sensitivity. Have added a demo link to regex101.com as well (bottom).

Comment: Just to mention, you can also use `(?i:picture|see|lorem)`

Comment: When you want to change the items of an array, you can do it with a `foreach` loop using the reference operator `&`: `foreach ($text as &$item) $item = preg_replace($regex, '', $item);`. It is shorter,  but it's useless here since `preg_replace` can take an array as subject parameter, so: `$text = preg-replace($regex, '', $text);` should suffice.

Comment: Using `.*?` around the words doesn't guarantee that the words are inside the brackets, since `.*?` can match a closing or an opening bracket.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: So a `[^)]+?` would be better in your opinion?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Good point, thanks for pointing it out. Updated your regex https://regex101.com/r/eY0qJ5/2 and will update my answer now.

Comment: @Jan please review your old answer.  Why does your negated character class have a lazy `?` after `*`?  Why not just feed the whole array to `array_replace()` just once?  I think some wordboundaries would be a good idea, but anubhava has already built this into his answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa: Any particular reason, you‘re reading an answer that is five years old?

Comment: @Jan I do not discriminate by page age while curating php-tagged content on SO.  A new answer was posted here (and since has been deleted) -- the activity bumped it to the top of the Active Questions list so I reviewed the page.  I also review lots of old pages while searching for dupe targets to close new questions.  It's all part of good curation and making SO a better resource for researchers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex for searching:

```
\h*\([^)]*\b(?:picture|see|lorem)\b[^)]*\)
```

Which means

```
\h*                    # match 0 or more horizontal spaces
\(                     # match left (
[^)]*                  # match 0 or more of any char that is not )
\b                     # match a word boundary
(?:picture|see|lorem)  # match any of the 3 keywords
\b                     # match a word boundary
[^)]*                  # match 0 or more of any char that is not )
\)                     # match right )
```

and replace by empty string:

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oJ0gC9/5)

**Code:**

```
$re = '/\h*\([^)]*\b(?:picture|see|lorem)\b[^)]*\)/'; 

$result = preg_replace($re, '', $input);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to make the regex detect if the *opening* bracket has an empty space before it, and if it does, when remove brackets, remove that empty space too. Otherwise, you are left with double spaces. Also, for completion, can you please add your regex in a preg_replace() statement.

Comment: I had `\h*` before `(` which was matching 0 or whitespaces that can be changed to `\h+` to match 1 or more whitespaces before `(` (see updated answer)

Comment: Thank you for the update, although it doesn't detect if brackets if there is no white space next to the opening bracket (which it should). Please see this example: https://regex101.com/r/oJ0gC9/4

Comment: In your input there is no space after `(` and it does remove space before `(`. You are getting confused with regex101 highlighted output.