# Regex - If string doesn't contain specific word within bracket, then remove bracket and its content

Tags: python, regex

Using Regex, I want to remove some words within brackets, except containing certain words.

Target words are:

```
hoho
haha
```

So I want to change this string:

```
"Nice (foo line) (haha great) (bar) (hoho how)"
```

to

```
"Nice (haha great) (hoho how)"
```

I tried some expresseions with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971710/regex-if-string-contains-specific-word-within-bracket-then-remove-bracket-and/35971793), but I couldn't find any answer. What should I do?

Comment: Please explain "it doesn't work. It seems to work only once."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not opposed to using some python in addition to regex, you can break apart the word groups, then search each group for the patterns you want to keep.  Finally, join the kept groups together into a single string.

```
import re

s = "Nice (foo line) (haha great) (bar) (hoho how)"

' '.join(x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'\([\w\s]+\)|\b\w+\b',s)
         if re.search(r'^[\w\s]+$|hoho|haha', x.group()))
# returns:
'Nice (haha great) (hoho how)'
```

Comment: It doesn't work if string contains period. "Nice (foo line) (haha.great) (bar) (hoho how)" returns "Nice haha great (hoho how)". Should I change regex in re.finditer?

Comment: Solved by adding dot in regex. Thanks.